# Renaming event handlers of a legacy WinForms application using Resharper

Tags: c#, winforms, resharper

I'm working on a WinForms project that uses this naming style for event handlers:

```
On[ControlName][EventName]
```

And I would like to rename *all* the event handlers in the project to the default style:

```
[ControlName]_[EventName]
```

I'm using ReSharper 7.1.3. I changed the naming style for event handlers (Options -> C# -> C# Naming Style -> Advanced -> Event subscriptions on fields).

However, it is highlighting the new event handlers that I add, but not the previous (legacy) event handlers (it seems like it doesn't recognize them as event handlers).

What am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but are you sure the ones you're looking at are event handlers? Usually methods using the On... naming style are the method wrappers that throw events, not the event handlers.

Comment: Hi Tim, I appreciate your question, not silly at all. Yes, I am looking at the event handlers, for example the Click event handler of a Button control - private void OnSaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e) . Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use Resharper for this, I'd just do a straightforward regex text find/replace for `void On{.+}\(object sender, EventArgs e\)`.